# How to validate the form field using input append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created the form with multiple form field using html and jquery. Form fields have Firstname,Email, Mobile No,No Of Refer.No of Refer was selection option. I need put validation firstname and mobile,City. How can I do this. 
code is

```js
/*$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("#select_btn").val('0');
    $('#select_btn').change(function(e) {
        var selno = $(this).val();
  $('#input').empty();
  for(i=0; i < selno; i++ ){
  $('#input').append('<div class="input'+i+'"><h2>'+(i+1)+'</h2><p> Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> </p> <p> Mobile:<input type="text" name="mob" /></p><p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></p><p>City: <select id="city" name="City"><option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option><option value="Chennai">Chennai</option><option value="Delhi">Delhi</option><option value="Jammu">Jammu</option><option value="Ooty">Ooty</option></select></p><p>Course: <select id="course" name="Course"><option value="B.com">B.com</option><option value="B.A">B.A</option><option value="MBA">MBA</option><option value="B.Sc">B.Sc</option><option value="BCA">BCA</option></select></p></div>');
  }
    });
});*/
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select#select_btn').change(function(){
 
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
 if(sel_value==0)
 {
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  $("#form1").css({'display':'none'});
 }
 else{
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  
  //Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically 
     create(sel_value);
  
  //appending submit button to form
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<input/>",{type:'submit', value:'Register'})
  )
  } 
 }); 
 
function create(sel_value){
   for(var i=1;i<=sel_value;i++)   
    {
    $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
    
     $("div#form1").append(
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
  $("<h3/>").text("Registration Form"+i)),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Name', name:'name_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Mobile', name:'mobile'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Email'+i, name:'email_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  //$('select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One',name:'city',placeholder:'City'+i})),
  $("<hr/>"),
  $("<br/>")
                  ))
     }
 
 }
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container">
   <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="player_email" />
    </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </p>
     <p> Refer:

<div id="selected_form_code">
 <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">--Select--</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
 </div>

 <div id="form1"> 
  <form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
   <!-- dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates here-->
  </form>
 </div> 
<!------ right side advertisement div ----------------->

 
</div>
</body>
```

Updated Code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select#select_btn').change(function(){
 
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
 if(sel_value==0)
 {
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  $("#form1").css({'display':'none'});
 }
 else{
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  
  //Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically 
     create(sel_value);
  
  //appending submit button to form
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<input/>",{type:'submit', value:'Register'})
  )
  } 
 }); 
 
function create(sel_value){
   for(var i=1;i<=sel_value;i++)   
    {
    $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
    
     $("div#form1").append(
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
  $("<h3/>").text("Registration Form"+i)),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Name', name:'name_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Mobile', name:'mobile'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Email'+i, name:'email_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  //$('select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One',name:'city',placeholder:'City'+i})),
  $("<hr/>"),
  $("<br/>")
                  ))
     }
 
 }
 
 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be help- change your `$(document).ready()` code like:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#select_btn").val('0');
    $('#select_btn').change(function(e) {
    var selno = $(this).val();
    $('#input').empty();
    for(i=0; i < selno; i++ ){

$('#input').append('<div class="input'+i+'"><h2>'+(i+1)+'</h2><p> Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> </p> <p> Mobile:<input type="text"   name="mob" /></p><p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></p><p>City:     <select id="city" name="City"><option value="0">--Select City--</option><option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option><option value="Chennai">Chennai</option><option value="Delhi">Delhi</option><option value="Jammu">Jammu</option><option value="Ooty">Ooty</option></select></p><p>Course: <select id="course" name="Course"><option value="B.com">B.com</option><option value="B.A">B.A</option><option value="MBA">MBA</option><option value="B.Sc">B.Sc</option><option value="BCA">BCA</option></select></p></div>');
}
});

$('#mySubmit').click(function() {
var total = $('#select_btn').val();

for(var i=0;i<total;i++) {
    if($('.input'+i).find('p input[name="name"]').val() == '') {
        alert('name should not be null');
        return false;
    }
    if($('.input'+i).find('p input[name="mob"]').val() == '') {
        alert('mobile should not be null');
        return false;
    }

    if($('.input'+i).find('#city').val() == '0') {
        alert('city should not be null');
        return false;
    }
}

});
});
```

and submit button should `<input type="submit" value="Join!" id="mySubmit" />`

I think this is not proper answer but it will help you to solve this.

Comment: Hi Patel, I need to validate the name ,mobile and email using regex. and i need to put mandatory field name,mobile no and city. Based on empty field throw the error message. For example city is empty means throw error "Please Select your City"

Comment: i think you should directly change in HTML like... `<input type="text" name="Name" required maxlength = "50"/>` and `<input type="email" name="Name" required maxlength = "50"/>` so it will directly validates.

Comment: Yes i put that regex validation but i need to put the error message corrospending

Comment: add code `if($('.input'+i).find('p input[name="city"]').val() == '') {
            alert('city should not be null');
            return false;
        }` where we added code for name and mobile number... see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Patel i change js and i need to create city field using append method. How can i create & use select option using apped

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, you need to validate the format of the input.
For that you can use the attribute 'pattern' in your input.
It is using regex.

You may have a look to the W3C exemple [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5 then you can use the attributes.

FirstName : You can use pattern and max attribute for this.

```
<p>Name:
  <input type="text" name="Name" pattern="[A-Za-z]" maxlength = "50"/>
</p>
```

mobile :

```
<p>Mobile:
  <input type="text" name="mobile" pattern="[0-9]{10}"/>
</p>
```